# Set a cron every certain hours between certain hours

Tags: cron

How can I set a cron to run every 2 hours between 8 am and 5 pm for example? Is this possible?

Comment: please read the question, it's not in Google... it's not a normal every 2 hours cron, it's every 2 hours between 8 and 5...

Comment: I searched Google and it brought me here! Thanks for the question/answer it was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 99):

Actually, Alex's ([former](https://superuser.com/revisions/411407/1)) solution will run every **minute**, every 2 hours between 8 am and **3pm**. 
The right solution is:

```
0 8-17/2 * * * /path/command
```

Or even:

```
0 8,10,12,14,16 * * * /path/command
```

Which of course looks less nice, but still does what requested...

Comment: Why is it considered to be between 8am and 3pm if it will run at 4pm?

Comment: @Aleksey, Alex's [solution before being edited](http://superuser.com/revisions/411407/2) ran from 8am to 3pm, which is not what the OP wants and also that's the reason I added this answer of mine and made a comment of that, if you read everything carefully you should get it...

Answer (score 10):

```
0 8-17/2 * * * your_command.sh
```